# EXCEL: Formula for processing a request

Tags: excel

I have a column (M) which contains drop-down lists for a request.
In column 'N' I would like to check to see if the item in column 'M' on the same row has been used on any OTHER row in column 'O' (which also uses the same list)...

and if it hasn't then select the same item from the list in column 'O' and display the word "Yes" in column 'N' ("Application Success" column)...

and if it has already been used by someone else, put the next item in the list that hasn't been used into column 'O' instead and display the word "No" in column 'N'.

This must work for each row in a table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If possible this needs to be done using only formulas and formatting, however macros are an option, avoid if you know a way that doesn't involve them.

Comment: It depends what kind of drop-down list you mean.  There's three or four different kinds in Excel.  Describe to use how you are making the drop-down lists so that we can tell what kind it is.

Comment: I'm using Data Validation, under "Allow" I've chosen List, then referenced the list which is on a separate sheet